# Transferring the folder and all its file to github

Tags: git, github, push

I want to transfer the entire my Java project including many nested folders and files to my github account.

How can I do this easily, I tried following steps but not able to see the folder on github.

Steps followed

```
1. Created the repo on github
2. Using Powershell on windows to the directory that has all 
   my source files and folders, I entered git init().
3. git add .
4. git commit -m "New Push all files"
5. git remote add origin https://github.com/name/my_project.git
6. git pull origin master
7. git push origin master
```

But I am not seeing the nested folders and the files on web account.

Can anyone please help me here. Appreciate your help in learning Git.

Thanks

Comment: What's the output of your commands? See any errors?

Answer (score 0):

> Using Powershell on windows

Instead of `Powershell` its better to use [Sourcetree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) or the [git-bash](https://git-scm.com/downloads):

---

> But I am not seeing the nested folders and the files on web account.

You need to add all your files recursively:

```
git add . -A
```

---

#### Do those steps as before (with minor changes as you can see):

```
git init
git add . -A
git commit -m "Message..."
git remote add origin git@github.com:<user>/<repo>.git
git push -u origin master
```